# Plotting a graph based on SQLite databse column

Tags: android, sqlite, graph

I want to create a graph based on the data in my SQLite database column. I have installed the achartengine.jar and I also know how to generate a graph on hard coded values in an array. 
But I am not able to figure out how to do it with the Sqlite data. 
Can anybody help me with links to tutorials on how to achieve this or maybe help me convert the database column into an array which I could use.

Thanks for any help!!

```
public class ReportGraph extends GraphicalActivity
{

    double[] fQty;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getIntent();

    }

    public Intent getIntent(Context context)
    {

        FuelStoredInfo reportInfo =new FuelStoredInfo(this);
        reportInfo.open();
        fQty=reportInfo.getReportData(this);
        reportInfo.close();



        CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Reports");
        for(int i = 0; i< fQty.length; i++)
        {
            series.add("Report"+(i+1), fQty[i]);

        }   



        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
        //dataset.addSeries(series1.toXYSeries());

        //customize bar 1
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer.setChartValuesSpacing((float)0.5);
        renderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);




        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer rRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        rRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        rRenderer.setChartTitle("Reports");
        rRenderer.setXTitle("Date");
        rRenderer.setYTitle("Prices");


        Intent i =ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, dataset, rRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);

    return i;

    }


    public double[] getfQty() {
        return fQty;
    }

    public void setfQty(double[] fQty) {
        this.fQty = fQty;



}
```

FuelStoredInfo.java (Database)

```
public FuelStoredInfo open() throws SQLiteException
    {
        OpenDBHelper ourHelper = new openDBHelper(ourContext);
               SQLiteDatabase   ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;

    }

    public double[] getReportData(ReportGraph reportGraph)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String [] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROW_ID, KEY_KM, KEY_FUEL_QTY, KEY_FUEL_PRICE, KEY_TOTAL_COST, KEY_MILEAGE, KEY_DATE,KEY_TANK_FULL};

             double[] reportList ;
                int i = 0;

                String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM fuel_table";

               reportCursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                int count = reportCursor.getCount();
                reportList = new double[count];

                if (reportCursor.moveToFirst()) 
                {
                    do {
                        reportList[i] = reportCursor.getDouble(2);
                        i++;

                        } while (reportCursor.moveToNext());
                }


                return reportList;
        }
```

Error log-->

```
07-23 13:16:11.393: E/AndroidRuntime(991): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-23 13:16:11.393: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
07-23 13:16:11.393: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
07-23 13:16:11.393: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
07-23 13:16:11.393: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at com.example.fuelcheck.FuelStoredInfo.open(FuelStoredInfo.java:104)
07-23 13:16:11.393: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at com.example.fuelcheck.ReportGraph.getIntent(ReportGraph.java:36)
```

Comment: [Inspire from here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: @CRUSADER Thanks for commenting. But I already have my database setup and working. I just cant figure out how to convert a certain column into an array and use it further in plotting a graph.

Comment: What you mean is you want to return String array from  your db column.. Right??

Comment: @CRUSADER yes. I want to use the values from the DB column as points to plot a graph

Comment: @CRUSADER It was some stupid errors that I had been doing. Just corrected them..Your code worked out just fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample you can use..

```
public String[] getAllContacts() {
    String[] contactList ;
    int i = 0;
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;//You fetch query

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    contactList = new String[count];
    // looping through all rows and adding to array
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            contactList[i] = cursor.getString(0);//getting data from column 0
            i++;
            // Adding contact to list
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}
```

I have fetched data from column 0, but you can fetch any column...

Hope this helps..

Comment: Post your code in your question so that we can guide you..

Comment: @PoojaGaonkar check `reportCursor != null`.. Is there any data in  fuel_table??

Comment: check count value you get from `reportCursor.getCount()` is not zero

Comment: Ok so Ijust got rid of the null pointer exception. The graph page opens all right but doesnt show the graph :(

Comment: Now, the graph page is open that means, either you haven't passed anything as input OR there is some handled exception in there(maybe invalid value). See logcat for details..

Comment: It was some stupid errors that I had been doing. Just corrected them..Your code worked out just fine. Thanks again.